# How to organize views in Laravel breeze?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

This may be a dumb question, but I've started exploring Laravel Breeze with vue and I'm not sure how to manage resources and their views.  (Using Laravel 9)

For example, if I have a table 'members' and a resource controller 'MemberController', ordinarily in the web.php file I would do something like:

```
Route::resource('members', MemberController::class)->names('members');
```

Then I'd create a 'member' folder in my resource/views folder to store the views for that table.  I could then call the view from the MemberController something like:

```
public function index()
{
  $members = Member::all();
  return view('member.index', compact('members'));
}
```

I'm trying to do something similar using vue in breeze, so I guess I'd have the vue pages in the 'resources/js/Pages' folder.  But this didn't seem to work properly.

I don't know how to transition from the previous approach of handling resources and views to Breeze using vue.

What's the recommended way to handle resources in an SPA with Breeze/vue?

Comment: You may wish to take a look at inertia.js which handles the whole application through a front-end app. Also, just as a side note, your question is quite broad and possibly opinion based which isn't always the best SO question

Comment: Thanks, Ill take a look at that.  Sorry for the broad question, I'm just not sure how to approach it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following Djave's suggestion, I took a look at the sample app from inertia.js and that answered everything.

The problem I had was due to using the dot notation when specifying the path to the vue page.  So, in my example above, it should instead be like this:

```
return view('Member/Index', compact('members'));
```

The inertia sample app code has a lot of good examples!